# Sencha GXT or SmartGWT for WebApp with Browser and Tablet Support

Tags: java, ipad, smartgwt, gxt

i currently look at 2 GWT Widget Libraries.
SmartGWT and Sencha GXT.

unfortunalty lots of the Questions here ons StackOverflow are dated quite a while back. So things might have changed.

What are your experiences with SmartGWT and GXT.
Especially the Support for Mobile Devices like IPads or GalaxyPads, also Smartphones in rendom cases.

SmartGWT offers SmartGwt.Mobile and GXT has Sencha Touch. Anybody used it so far?
haven't found lots of Informaiton in the Internet :(
It is importent for us that we can develop in Java, as we have people who don't want to do a lot of JavaScript...

hope you guys can help me out :)

Greets

Comment: You can also use pure GWT with mgwt for a mobile version: http://www.m-gwt.com/

Comment: Sencha Touch isn't Java is it?  Isn't it extjs and not GXT based????

Comment: Sencha touch is not java, Touch4j is

Answer (score 0):

Smartgwt to me works great since it has a lot of widgets that are simpler to write under SmartGWT LGPL(Free/open source). However the alignment and sizing of the widgets need to be revised, it has alot to do with css than plain java. for some time,ypu still needs to dive in into the css. Smartgwt.Mobile is very fine. To me there are two things that GXT scores, The blue theme is looks great than that of smartgwt, The Statistics/Graphical presentation of data is Great!(http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:linegapchart) 
PLEASE FOLLOW SHOWCASES OF TWO UI VENDERS http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#portlet_events_portal_layout